# R if condition never satisfies and always false

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am new to R, and i'm doing my first bio-informatics assignment. So excuse me for any silly mistakes. I am having difficulties in looping through a data frame. What I want to do is read a sequence of dna from a file and convert it into amino acid codons. The problem arises when I am trying to convert the 3-nucleic bases into codons.

I have the `bases.csv` file as follows with codons for 3-nucleic bases. The contents are:

```
a, b, c, amino
A, G, G, R
A, G, A, R
A, G, C, S
A, G, T, S
A, A, G, K
A, A, A, K
A, A, C, N
A, A, T, N
A, C, G, T
A, C, A, T
A, C, C, T
A, C, T, T
A, T, G, M
A, T, A, I
A, T, C, I
A, T, T, I
C, G, G, R
C, G, A, R
C, G, C, R
C, G, T, R
C, A, G, Q
C, A, A, Q
C, A, C, H
C, A, T, H
C, C, G, P
C, C, A, P
C, C, C, P
C, C, T, P
C, T, G, L
C, T, A, L
C, T, C, L
C, T, T, L
T, G, G, W
T, G, C, C
T, G, T, C
T, A, C, Y
T, A, T, Y
T, C, G, S
T, C, A, S
T, C, C, S
T, C, T, S
T, T, G, L
T, T, A, L
T, T, C, F
T, T, T, F
G, G, G, G
G, G, A, G
G, G, C, G
G, G, T, G
G, A, G, E
G, A, A, E
G, A, C, D
G, A, T, D
G, C, G, A
G, C, A, A
G, C, C, A
G, C, T, A
G, T, G, V
G, T, A, V
G, T, C, V
G, T, T, V
```

EDIT:
FULL SOURCE CODE:

```
lines <- c(readLines("demo.txt"))
bases <- read.csv(file="bases.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")


gene_start <- FALSE
gene <- ""
amino <- ""

convert_to_amino <- function(a, b, c) {
    index <- 1
    while (index <= nrow(bases)) {
        if ((bases[index, 'a'] == a) && (bases[index, 'b'] == b) && (bases[index, 'c'] == c)) {
            return (bases[index, 'amino'])
        }

        index <- index + 1

    }


}



lines <- strsplit(lines, "")[[1]]
i <- 0
while ((i + 2 < length(lines))) {

    if (gene_start == FALSE) {

        if (lines[i] == 'A' && lines[i + 1] == 'T' && lines[i + 2] == 'G') {
            gene_start <- TRUE
            print ("gene found")
            amino <- convert_to_amino(lines[i], lines[i+1], lines[i+2])
            gene <- paste(gene, amino, sep="")
            i <- i + 3
        }

        i <- i + 1 

    }

    else if (gene_start == TRUE) {

        if ((lines[i] == 'T' && lines[i + 1] == 'A' && lines[i + 2] == 'A') || (lines[i] == 'T' && lines[i + 1] == 'A' && lines[i + 2] == 'G') || (lines[i] == 'T' && lines[i + 1] == 'G' && lines[i + 2] == 'A')) {

            gene_start <- FALSE
            print (gene)
            gene <- ""
        }

        else {
            amino <- convert_to_amino(lines[i], lines[i+1], lines[i+2])
            gene <- paste(gene, amino, sep="")
        }

        i <- i + 3
    } 

    else
        i <- i + 1
}
```

what I want to achieve here is check if the combination of `a`, `b`, `c` bases is present in the dataframe. If it is then assign it the respectiv amino acid code.
But according to the output the `if` condition is never satisfied. Any pointers on whats wrong here would be helpful.

Comment: How are you converting the CSV file to a data frame?

Comment: `bases <- read.csv(file="bases.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")`

Comment: I just loaded your data frame and function locally, and the code works completely fine for the function call `convert_to_amino('A', 'G', 'G')` ... how are you using the function?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Updated the question with full source code

Comment: Your logic has a problem.  For instance, I notice that in the first `if` condition, if it be true, then you would be passing `ATG` into the amino function, which would not find a match.  I suspect a similar problem with the entire `if-else` construct.   You need to review the logic behind your script and correct it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen actually `ATG` is present in the CSV file, i just didn't upload the full file. I'm updating the CSV file as well in the answer.

Comment: I mean tte contents of the file

Comment: Mind providing a sample of demo.txt?

Comment: It just contains a DNA sequence. `CATGTTTCCACTTACAGATCCTTCAAAAAGAGTGTTTCAAAACTGCTCTATGAAAAGGAATGTTCAACTCTGTGAGTTAAATAAAAGCATCAAAAAAAAGTTTCTGAGAATGCTTCTGTCTAGTTTTTATGTGAAGATATTTCCATTTTCTCTATAAGCCTCAAAGCTGTCCAAAT
`

Comment: I think you might be re-inventing the wheel, there must be a package that converts sequence to amino? Maybe https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seqinr/seqinr.pdf

Comment: But unfortunately this assignment requires me to built one my self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I did find a way that seems to work, it's clumsy, though.
First instead of having `bases`as a 4 columns dataframe I worked with a 2 columns dataframe.

```
ref=bases
ref$amino=as.character(ref$amino)
ref$codon=paste0(ref$a,ref$b,ref$c)
ref$codon=gsub(" ","",ref$codon)
ref=ref[,c("amino","codon")]
```

It looks like:

```
   amino codon
1      R   AGG
2      R   AGA
3      S   AGC
4      S   AGT
5      K   AAG
```

Now with `demo`: `CATGTTTCCACTTACAGATCCTTCAAAAAGAGTGTTTCAAAACTGCTCTATGA` (only a sample of yours)

```
demo="CATGTTTCCACTTACAGATCCTTCAAAAAGAGTGTTTCAAAACTGCTCTATGA"
demo<- strsplit(demo, "(?<=.{3})", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
```

This turns into into bits of 3 letters, the codons (the last bit is only 2 because I chose the length of the sample randomly)

```
> demo
 [1] "CAT" "GTT" "TCC" "ACT" "TAC" "AGA" "TCC" "TTC" "AAA" "AAG" "AGT" "GTT" "TCA" "AAA" "CTG" "CTC" "TAT" "GA"
```

I then associate each codon with the reference from `ref`:

```
sapply(demo,function(x)ref$amino[x==ref$codon])
```

Which gives (only a sample):

```
   $CAT
[1] " H"

$GTT
[1] " V"

$TCC
[1] " S"

$ACT
[1] " T"
```

This is a list so the format may require further reworking. The results match your references.

Answer (score 1):

We can convert sequence to 3 column dataframe then merge with bases:

```
# dummy input
x <- "CATGTTTCCACTTACAGATCCTTCAAAAAGAGTGTTTCAAAACTGCTCTATGAAAAGGAATGTTCAACTCTGTGAGTTAAATAAAAGCAT"
nchar(x)
# [1] 90

# convert input to a dataframe with 3 columns matching bases columns
xdf <- data.frame(t(matrix(unlist(strsplit(x, "")), nrow = 3)))
colnames(xdf) <- colnames(bases)[1:3]
xdf$ix <- seq(nrow(xdf))
head(xdf)
#   a b c ix
# 1 C A T  1
# 2 G T T  2
# 3 T C C  3
# 4 A C T  4
# 5 T A C  5
# 6 A G A  6

# merge to get amino column
xdfAmino <- merge(xdf, bases, all.x = TRUE)

# mark non-matches with "_"
xdfAmino$amino[is.na(xdfAmino$amino)] <- "_"

# result
paste(xdfAmino$amino[order(xdfAmino$ix)], collapse = "")
#[1] "HVSTYRSFKKSVSKLLYEKECSTL_VK_KH"
```